# spring boot application with gradle build cannot find index.html

Tags: angularjs, gradle, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application, with gradle build.

I have static/index.html under main/resources. when server starts up, trying to access index.html returns 404 complaining that there is no mapping found for URI.

any insight?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the static resources in `main/resources` then they are in the wrong place. They should be in `src/main/resources`, i.e. the path of your `index.html` file should be `src/main/resources/static/index.html`.

Comment: yes, that is exactly where it is. it is under src/main/resources/static/index.html, but after packaging, it cannot access it